# docusign unable to use attachment tabs by API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign's sandbox environment and also API Explorer.

I need some help to create envelopes by API for request attachments for signers. I've seen in this [page](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-user-guide-advanced-sending-request-documents) it might not be enabled in some accounts. But I'm not sure if this is the case once I can request attachments by sending envelops from user's portal.

Also on API Explorer I'm not being able to include attachment tabs, as you can see in this print:

[image]

By API calls, I'm trying to include `signerAttachmentTabs` as I've seen on their documents.

No errors, it seem my `signer_attachment_tabs` are just ignored. Hope some one can help me to find out why it is not working by API calls.

Thanks,
Etore

Answer (score 0):

[SignerAttachementTabs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Signer%20Attachment%20Tab.htm) are fully supported but are not yet included in the API Explorer. The next version of the Explorer will let you use them from the Explorer.

Accounts on the Demo/Sandbox platform enable you to include SignerAttachmentTabs.

Please use the documentation to try creating an Envelopes::Create call that includes a SignerAttachmentTab. If you have problems, ask another question here and include your code that is not working.